# Runtime Error in Async Task

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build a simple program using Asycn Task that on clicking get button loads google home page in webview. I have no errors showing up in code however when I click the get button it crashes with the following error:

**An error occured while executing doInBackground() 
java.lang.RuntimeException:java.lang.Throwable:A WebView method was called on thread 'AsyncTask #1'.All WebView methods must be called on the same thread**

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.asyncts2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

              button1.setEnabled(false);
              DownloadWebPageTask task =  new DownloadWebPageTask();
              task.execute(new String[] {"http://www.google.com/"});
        }
    });
}

private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(urls[0]);
        return "Done";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is Log Cat errors

Can anyone point me to where I am going wrong? Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy way to handle that is to, whenever and wherever you want to access or modify the WebView, do it in the uithread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //shake the webView here!
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: since I am new to android , can u plz elaborate where to put this method.

Comment: wherever you´ve got `webView.dothisordothat`... use the code I´ve pasted and put the `webView.dothisordothat` instead of `//shake the webView here!`

Comment: thanks a lot man it worked well, but only problem this time is that webview is displaying : page not available.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use an AsyncTask to load an URL in a webview. If you want to trigger an action when loading is complete, do like this :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

doInBackground() method not runs in the UI thread. It runs as a separate thread which will not interact with UI. Thats why, It is not able to access your WebView which is present in UI thread. I really dont see the purpose of using an AsyncTask here. You can load your webview inside your onClick method itself. Otherwise, use onPostExecute() method to update your Webview.

Otherwise, As @eduyayo told, put the runOnUiThread() method inside your doInBackground() method and do the WebView updates inside the run() method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make those calls inside your main thread, i.e. inside your activity itself. Since AsyncTask create another thread, android restricts lots of action here. one simple way to go ahead is to mimmic call back handler . Steps to guide you ,

Create interface :

```
public interface IWebViewHandler {
    void handleWebCall();
}
```

Implement this interace by your activity and override the method with your action and call this method from your asynctask.doInBackground, like

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements IWebViewHandler {

@Override
    public void handleWebCall() {
        //your work like action on WebViews
    /*    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(urls[0]);*/

    }

    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            handleWebCall();

            return "Done";
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

P.S : the call to handleWebCall is just for sample, modify calling method and the method implementation /signature as per your neeed.